# Incompatible Types Android

Tags: java, android

I just pick this code in the java file of **DigitalPersona One Touch SDK**. I simple want to get the `DPFPSample` to return as Image. But I'm getting this error:

> Incompatible Types.
>
> Required: android.media.Image
>
> Found: java.awt.Image.

I'm not knowledgeable yet in both fields. Would you guys help me with this?

Here's the code:

```
protected Image convertSampleToBitmap(DPFPSample sample) {
  return DPFPGlobal.getSampleConversionFactory().createImage(sample); 'error on this line.
}
```

Comment: Android != Java SE, so your library is looking for Java AWT class which doesn't exist in Android. Unless you have source code for your library and some knowledge of both platforms it may not be possible to use it in Android.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is right it is not possible in android

Comment: Is there another way? Like converting the image to `Bitmap`.

Comment: Q: Are you sure you downloaded the Digital Persona SDK for Android (and not the Windows version)?

Comment: They say the SDK for Android is out seems I can't find where to download it. That's why I tried to imply the Java Sample on Digital Perosona SDK which is ya for Windows Version.

Comment: Simply you have imported wrong media type. It should be `android.media.Image` but you imported wrong with this `java.awt.Image`

Comment: Ya I though that there's another way of getting the `Image` from the `DFPFSample` which handles fringerprints.